# How to clear a div that is inside a firebase foreach

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to clear the messagebox div when im choosing another "user" from my user div. However when i'm trying to do so, only the latest message from firebase gets into the chat bubble div.

```
$('div.chat_list').on('click', function () { //populate chatbox and determine clicked user

     var $cl = $(this).closest('div.chat_list');
     var $chtName = $cl.attr('id');
     $('div.chat_list').removeClass("active_chat");
     $($cl).addClass("active_chat");
     var thread = firebase.database().ref("messages/" + brgy + "/" + key).orderByChild("chatroom").equalTo($chtName); //populates chat list from that barangay (names)
     thread.on("value", snaps => {
         if (snaps.exists()) { //populate chat entries for users
             snaps.forEach(snaps => {
                 username = snaps.child("uid").val();
                 message = snaps.child("message").val();
                 date = snaps.child("date").val();
                 time = snaps.child("time").val();
                 console.log(username + ": " + message);

                 if (username != key) { //sets the chat bubble type
                     div1 = "outgoing_msg";
                     div2 = "sent_msg";
                 } else {
                     div1 = "incoming_msg";
                     div2 = "recieved_msg";
                 }

                 $(".msg_history").empty();
                 $(".msg_history").append("<div class='" + div1 + "'>" +
                     "<div class='" + div2 + "'>" +
                     "<div class='received_withd_msg'>" +
                     "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
                     "<span class='time_date'> " + time + " | " + date + " </span>" +
                     "</div></div></div>");

             });
         }

     });

 })
```

This line, `$(".msg_history").empty();` is what causes the problem.

What i'm trying to achieve here is, i want to have a clean "Chatbox" when im selecting a new user to chat with. Thats why i have the `.empty` tag, but doing this only appends the last message. not all the messages, to the chat bubble div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to empty the div first before appending data to it, so it won't be cleared on each iteration.
your code should be like this :

```
$('div.chat_list').on('click', function () { //populate chatbox and determine clicked user

     var $cl = $(this).closest('div.chat_list');
     var $chtName = $cl.attr('id');
     $('div.chat_list').removeClass("active_chat");
     $($cl).addClass("active_chat");
     var thread = firebase.database().ref("messages/" + brgy + "/" + key).orderByChild("chatroom").equalTo($chtName); //populates chat list from that barangay (names)
     thread.on("value", snaps => {
         if (snaps.exists()) { //populate chat entries for users
             // empty the container first
             $(".msg_history").empty();
             // then populate data 
             snaps.forEach(snaps => {
                 username = snaps.child("uid").val();
                 message = snaps.child("message").val();
                 date = snaps.child("date").val();
                 time = snaps.child("time").val();
                 console.log(username + ": " + message);

                 if (username != key) { //sets the chat bubble type
                     div1 = "outgoing_msg";
                     div2 = "sent_msg";
                 } else {
                     div1 = "incoming_msg";
                     div2 = "recieved_msg";
                 }

                 $(".msg_history").append("<div class='" + div1 + "'>" +
                     "<div class='" + div2 + "'>" +
                     "<div class='received_withd_msg'>" +
                     "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
                     "<span class='time_date'> " + time + " | " + date + " </span>" +
                     "</div></div></div>");

             });
         }

     });

 })
```

Comment: i must have gotten confused doing this, because i've inserted the empty after the click function, and thought that if it doesnt work there then it wont work anywhere on the top of the function